# "I am a (some description) who..." OR "I am a (some description) that..."?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

I am cleaning up my CV and was curious about how to correctly phrase the following:

> I am a highly motivated software developer **who** loves solving...

OR

> I am a highly motivated software developer **that** loves solving...

More generally, what is the grammatical rule for the usage of **who** and **that** in similar contexts?

Comment: It's fine but generally one places sentences at the top with a series of points and action verbs but no personal pronoun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Who" is used for sentient beings. "That" is used for objects or insentient living things like plants.